# ASP.NET Identity: attempting to add user with existing ID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET Identity version 1.0

What is the default behavior of UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password) method call if we are trying to add an user with ID already existing in database?

I'm asking because some time ago the following line of code

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

returned an IdentityResult object with not empty Errors list saying something like "User with ID [ID] already exists".

But now (we didn't do much changes since that) we've got an exception when attempting to insert new user record in the database. 
In both cases UserManager.CreateAsync calls FindByNameAsync in our IUserStore implementation and that method finds and returns a correct User object.

How can I see the internal implementation of UserManager.CreateAsync method? 
Does it check new User object for existence before calling CreateAsync of IUserStore?
I guess it does (since it calls FindByNameAsync but it seems it does not consider found User object as "existing".

Comment: Does "Go to definition" work? If not, you can always check the APS.MVC code on GitHub.

Comment: UserManager.CreateAsync call the Insert method of UserTable in custom providers

Comment: @AndreiV Identity framework is not part of MVC stack and not open-sourced yet -((

Comment: It is highly recommended to update to Identity 2.1 - a lot of problems in Identity v1 have been addressed. And to see implementation of `UserManager` you'll have to use decompiler, like DotPeek(my favourite).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer using DotPeek (thanks trailmax for his suggestion).
Yes, UserManager.CreateAsync makes validation (via UserValidator class) and the validator (among other conditions) has the following piece of code:

```
    TUser owner = await this.Manager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
    if ((object) owner != null && owner.Id != user.Id)
      errors.Add(...);
```

So, as we see it checks if the user with this UserName already exists BUT the error is thrown only if the Id of that user differs from the Id of User object we are trying to create.

Since we generated Id before insertion and it actually equals to User's email - that caused the problem. The solution is simple: it's better to generate user's Id right before it's inserted into database.